# Is it possible to load a Google Map into a div and then overlay a canvas element over it?

Tags: html, google-maps, canvas

I know that you can load an image directly in a canvas with
`drawImage()`, but I'm wondering if it is possible to overlay a canvas
over another div with images in it.

Specifically, I want to overlay a `<canvas>` element over a Google map.
I'd like to draw polylines and do animations over the map in the
`<canvas>` context instead of using the Google Map APIs for this
purpose.

Comment: If what you're going for is to have the background of a canvas to be transparent; I don't believe that's possible; but then again, I haven't worked to much with the `<canvas>`.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea -- to have the <canvas> element transparent.

Comment: This example shows layering of canvas elements on top of each other, but not putting an div with an image behind the bottom canvas layer: http://html5.litten.com/using-multiple-html5-canvases-as-layers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It should work just fine. Simply have your canvas be positioned over the div, similar to how the multiple canvases are positioned over each other in the example you linked.

You could probably just have tried it and not had to wait for an answer on SO :)